# webkit private browsing losing controls from page

Tags: html, gwt, safari, webkit

I'm using GWT to render controls. In Safari (i.e. webkit), but only Safari (i.e. not Chrome's fork) when the browser is in private browsing mode one control fails to display, it is not there at all, but only this one control.

Does anyone know of limitations/faults of webkit with private browsing mode to do this? Here is the html, I apologise up front, but that is how GWT does things ;)

Basically it is a button with an image to the left and text to the right and on clicking it pops up a window.

Tbh, I'm struggling because the HTML shown in view source is absolutely nothing like the HTML you see in developer tools mode, so I'm thinking that when I look at the source I do not actually see the button but the form that gets popped up and in private browsing mode it's somehow not getting shown as it should.

the code you see below is the HTML I see in developer tools mode (F12), but when I look in 'view source' it is absolutely not like this and instead all I see is the actual rendered form code.

```
<td style="width: 222px; padding: 0px;">
    <div id="com.xxx.test.portal.provider.datasearch.client.dataSearch-dataSearch" widgetclass="com.xxx.test.portal.provider.datasearch.client.dataSearch">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <div>
                            <div class="com-sencha-gxt-core-client-resources-CommonStyles-CommonStylesDefaultAppearance-CommonDefaultStyles-inlineBlock com-sencha-gxt-core-client-resources-CommonStyles-CommonStylesDefaultAppearance-CommonDefaultStyles-unselectable" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true">
                                <div class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonCellXXXStyle-button com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonCellXXXStyle-small" style="">
                                    <table hidefocus="-1" class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-frame com-sencha-gxt-core-client-resources-CommonStyles-CommonStylesDefaultAppearance-CommonDefaultStyles-noFocusOutline" style="" tabindex="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-topLeft">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-top">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-topRight">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-left">
                                                    <div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-contentArea">
                                                    <div class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-content">
                                                        <div class=" com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonCellXXXStyle-iconLeft">
                                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonCellXXXStyle-mainTable">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td valign="middle" class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonCellXXXStyle-iconWrap">
                                                                            <img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="https://tst01.iop.test.xxx.com/cin/CIN/clear.cache.gif" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 0px 0px;" border="0" alt="">
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td valign="middle" style="">
                                                                                <div class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonCellXXXStyle-text">Search for a data</div>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-right">
                                                        <div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-bottomLeft">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-bottom">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="com-XXX-test-gxt-theme-blue-client-button-ButtonCellXXXAppearance-ButtonTableFrameXXX-bottomRight">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: Maybe your CSS class names are overflowing? :-D (j/k)

Comment: It would help if you showed the code for the missing element, and how it shows up in Developer Tools when not in private mode.